# ¿Cómo puedo generar archivos de EXCEL y PDF con NestJS?

Tags: nestjs

Actualmente estoy desarrollando un sistema de inventarios en NestJS, necesito empezar a generar reportes en PDF y EXCEL. Sin embargo no sé que librerías se pueden usar para este fin (y que tan buenas son en comparación con las librerias disponibles para PHP, tales como: phpspreadsheet y fpdf)

Answer (score 0):

Mira en el caso de EXCEL no lo he utilizado, pero para generar PDF te recomiendo usar PDFkit Table.

En este [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vg-9yr4hTE&t=30s) explican como utilizarlo desde cero, espero te sirva.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola Serge Manuel, bienvenido, te invito a que leas [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para evitar votos negativos y/o que tu repuesta sea eliminada. Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/377741)

Comment: Esta pregunta claramente no se responde en pocas palabras porque es todo un desarrollo, la respuesta incluye la libreria que necesita y el video linkeado explica todo el largo proceso... pero como consideren...saludos.